# Lost or corrupt mysql table after computer is turned off or restarted

Tags: mysql, database, osx-lion, database-connection

I'm using a mysql local database to store some data from two ruby scripts i created. The problem is that whenever I restart or turn off my computer my database seems to get corrupted as when i tried to access it it show the following error: 
`Can't connect to MySQL server on 'Andres-MacBook-Air-3.local' (61) (Mysql2::Error)`

I then use the following commands (which I found while googling around) to restore the connection:

```
cd /usr/local/mysql
sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe
(Enter your password, if necessary)
(Press Control-Z)
bg
```

After I do that, **I can connect to the database** but when I try to access a table the following error comes up:

```
Error retrieving table information
An error occurred while retrieving the information for table 'fourCheckins'. Please try again.

MySQL said: Table 'trackpuntos.fourcheckins' doesn't exist
```

I think that turning off/restarting my computer is causing the problem as this same scenario has happen to be twice. Fortunately after the first time I am doing regular mysqldumps.

Does anyone have an idea on why is this happening/how to prevent it?

I'm running mysql 5.6.12, on a macbook air running OS Lion.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've been having the same problem for the past week. I'm finding the InnoDB databases are getting corrupted when I have open connections to the databases and I shut off/restart the computer.

I had installed mysql 5.6 unintentionally via homebrew upgrade on my Mac. I just rolled mysql back to 5.5.29 following the instructions below. After the downgrade back to 5.5, I set up my databases again, opened a bunch of connections, and then shutdown the computer.  Upon reboot, I had no corruptions.  Hopefully it'll stay that way!

Note: paths may be different for your system

1. Uninstall 5.6 mysql via homebrew

   ```
   $ brew uninstall mysql
   $ rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
   ```
2. Install 5.5.29 mysql via homebrew

   ```
   $ cd /usr/local/Library/Formula
   $ git checkout -b mysql-5.5.29 336c97637c5449018cde59f7d2a87a298692da08
   $ brew install mysql
   ```
3. follow all the post-install steps for mysql...

   ```
   $ unset TMPDIR
   $ mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
   $ launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
   $ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
   ```
4. reset homebrew to master !important!

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   ```

Lastly, don't brew upgrade mysql until 5.6 is more stable!

Comment: Thanks @Uysrc ! I'll try that as i'm currently stopping my mysql server whenever I have to turn off/restart my computer. This weekend I'm moving my database into a server to also avoid this and then will try your solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after a reboot... Just stopped and restarted MySQL and my DB was working fine after that.